# How to visualise data where one variable is continuous and the other is categorical?

Tags: categorical-data, scatterplot, many-categories

This question is very simple but I have been struggling in getting the right script for this.

My data set goes as follows:

```
HZ  Condition
  5     A
  6     A
  3     A
  4     A
 10     B
  8     B
 11     B
 13     B
```

I want to build a scatter plot to visualize the correlation between HZ in A and Hz in B.

I thought it should be represented as x being "HZ" interacting with "Condition_A" and y being "HZ" interacting with "Condition_B", and grouping being "Condition".
Perhaps I am not tidying up my data properly, but I wonder if there is a way to make this directly, without adding more columns (as this is part of a data set with many other variables).

---

Thank you all for your replies.
The reason why I was not using boxplot is that, as Nick Cox pointed out, I want to show the distribution of HZ data points. I should have explained it better in my original post, but the aim is to check if HZ is increasing or decreasing in each condition, and that is why at first I thought having x-axis with "HZxA" and y-axis with "HZ$B". I will be using this variable to control for effect size another variable. So I will try to use Nick Cox visual representation example, thank you!
I also did not mention that I am using R, so the scripts are very appreciated indeed, thank you Robert Long and Cdalitz.

Answer (score 4):

I like to show the raw data but use a method that scales to large N better than dot plots, so I use spike histograms stratified by the categorical variable.  I add quantile intervals at the bottom of the histograms.  If using R `plotly` graphics you can turn the quantile intervals off and on and likewise for the mean and median.  An example may be found [here](http://hbiostat.org/R/Hmisc/examples.html#stratified-descriptive-statistics) along with other displays such as extended box plots and simple spike histograms.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options spring to mind. The first is a simple dot plot:

```r
HZ <- c(5,6,3,4,10,8,11,13)
Cond <- c(rep("A",4), rep("B",4))
dt <- data.frame(HZ, Cond)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt, aes(y = HZ, x = Cond, color = Cond)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

The second is a boxplot:

```r
ggplot(dt, aes(y = HZ, x = Cond, color = Cond)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question didn't mention R and how to code this in R or any other software is off-topic here in any case.

As an in-principle answer, consider also

[image]

My point is not this example -- many other displays would work well too -- but some small principles that apply to posts like this.

1. Box plots don't use the space available with 2 groups very well, and that is true for any other small number of groups. The box plot here is a simplified summary with whiskers to the extremes, defensible because detail is shown separately.
2. There is scope to show the individual data points too. With integer values the scope for ties in a full dataset is very high, so some way to show ties directly is helpful. Here the quantile plot display would work to show ties clearly: stacking or jittering data points could work almost or exactly as well.
3. There is no reason to suppose that median and quartiles are the only summaries of interest. The horizontal lines here show means, which happen to be identical in the data example. In other datasets, other summaries might make more sense, say geometric means or trimmed means.

Answer (score 0):

These are univariate data. Thus you are presumably not looking for a scatter plot, but for a boxplot:

```
boxplot(HZ ~ Condition, x)
```

where *x* denotes the data frame containing your data. This is only a display af summary statistics (median, quartiles). For showing the original points, the only builtin function seems to be *dotchart*:

```
dotchart(x$HZ, labels=x$Condition, col=as.numeric(x$Condition)
```

But this gives each point its own row. Apparently, with builtin tools, a workaround is required: First draw an empty plot, then add the points with *points*:

```
# we must use border="white",
# because type="n" is ignored for categorial x-values
plot(x$Condition, x$HZ, border="white")
points(x$Condition, x$HZ, col=x$Condition)
```

Comment: I see no reason to suppose that the OP is  or even should be looking for a boxplot. A scatter plot -- often in this circumstance called a dot plot, strip plot or by many other names -- is a fair idea for these data. Some device to avoid overplotting is a good idea, but that's a detail. (And these are bivariate data, one variable being categorical.)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have just noticed that *plot* by default automatically draws a boxplot, so this is the problem the OP presumably ran into. I have extended my answer how to solve this with vanilla R (the other answer requires third party packages).

Comment: Your answer is entirely constructive, but apart just possibly from the word "tidy" there is no mention of R in the post. I am not inclined to software wars but any assumption that everyone uses R is incorrect and any opinion that everyone should use R is beyond the scope of CV.

Comment: Good point. I cannot remember why I thought this was an R question. OTOH, it is unlikely that the OP asks how to draw points with a pencil ;-) And, quite likely, if R was mentioned in the question, the question would have been closed immediately by a moderator as off-topic...